# Why is wikipedia.summary(string) removing letters from my string?

Tags: python, nlp, wikipedia

I am working on a program that can search wikipedia given an input like: "Who is Elon Musk" - however, with his specific example (and others), when the variable is placed into wikipedia.summary(string), it removes the "l" in "Elon Musk". Attached is my function:

```
import wikipedia
import spacy
def search_wiki(self, search):
    nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
    doc = nlp(search)
    subject_phrase = get_subject_phrase(doc)
    try:
        results = wikipedia.page(str(subject_phrase)) #removes here
        final = results
        print(wikipedia.summary(final, sentences=1))
    except wikipedia.exceptions.PageError:
        results = wikipedia.search(str(subject_phrase))
        print("\nDid you mean " + results[0] + "?\n")
        possible = results[0]
        if input() == "yes":
            final = possible
            print(final) #prints "Elon Musk"
            print(wikipedia.summary(final, sentences=1)) #removes here too
        else:
            print("\nThese are the other searches that came up for " + str(subject_phrase) + ":\n")
            for r in results:
                print(r)
            print("\nPlease type the result you want me to search for:\n")
            final = input()
            print(wikipedia.summary(final, sentences=1))
    except wikipedia.exceptions.DisambiguationError as e:
        print("I couldn't find anything for " + str(subject_phrase) + ". Here are some related results:")
        for o in e.options:
            print(o)
        print("\nWhich of these did you mean?")
        final = input()
        print(wikipedia.summary(final, sentences=2))
    print("\nWould you like to hear more about " + final + "?\n")
    if input() == "yes":
        print("\nYou can read more about " + final + " at " + wikipedia.page(final).url + "\n")
        entry = wikipedia.summary(final, sentences=3)
        return lambda: entry, True
    else:
        entry = wikipedia.summary(final, sentences=1)
        return lambda: entry, False`
```

I am pretty stuck, I have the variable printing right before the call to wikipedia.summary(string), so I know that the variable is not changing on my end (or at least I think).

Comment: strings are immutable, so it's not possible for a function to change the value of a string argument. How are you seeing this removal?

Comment: @Barmar when I call wikipedia.summary(string), the function is returning results with missing letters (e.g. I search "gold" and it gives me results for "old")

Comment: I have a feeling this is an encoding issue of some kind.

Comment: Does this happen when you don't use spacy? If it's not related to nlp, please provide a simpler [mre] that demonstrates just the wikipedia problem.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. When I do `subject_phrase = 'Who is Elon Musk'` and then the rest of your code that calls wikipedia, the summary is `Business magnate Elon Musk initiated the acquisition of American social media company Twitter, Inc.`